# Content of article not showing

Tags: joomla, menu, header, article

I have a menu item that links to an article, I have the menu item shown in the page, but then the user clicks onto the link, it will only show the title of the article but not the content. I am not sure, what exactly is happening.

I checked the source of html, nope the content isnot there. although the content is there in the database. I ran the degbug mode, but it will give the correct article, only it wouldnt render the content.

One of the menu which was there from beginning acts as required but if I add any menuitems and article, I wont see the content.

Comment: Are you using the Joomla article Manager or K2? Are you using the most up to date version of your Joomla series? Have you been missing around with any core Joomla or template code? Are you sure you have given the article the correct permissions, for example made sure you have not set it to **special** so that only admins can view it?

Comment: I am using article manager, there is no special permission, its set to public. I havent really made any change to core joomla module, although I have been playing around with joomla content, menu, module table.

I dont think its problem with article manager as I see the content on another page which is the sibling of the one that is not working.

Comment: that is most likely your answer then. don't mess around with the Joomla core files or database tables and it can screw your security and functionality ;)

Comment: I dont think its because of me playing with the joomla table, other pages are displaying all fine, it is only with the menus I add to this particular location in menu hierarchy (at least it seems).

Comment: Don't change the core, extend it. Joomla is highly extensible and that makes it complex. You can't just change something especially something as important as the menu table and expect it to work.   If you tell us what you changed we might be able to help but it's hard to know.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, this is what solved it (using Joomla 3.2):

1. Clicked Extensions -> Template Manager to go to 'Template Manager: Styles'
2. Clicked on the style being used by the pages that did not show content, for me 'yoo_master - Default'
3. Under the profiles Tab, in the Content section I changed 'System Output' to 'Yes'

Then page content started showing again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Agressive cache enabled (Global Configuration > System) and the Cache plugin activated it might take a while before any changes will appear. Flush the cache (Maintainance > Clear Cache), and see if the content shows after that. Also some Template Frameworks (like T3) have their own cache layer which might prevent your content from showing up.

Otherwise there could be a problem in the template, rule that out by assigning the default Template.